# geom_smooth No grafica linea de tendencia

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplot

Quiero graficar una linea de tendencia en una grafica de puntos. al momento de graficar esta linea no aparece.

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
DatExp <- read.csv('D:/.../1_DetailProgressMine_CCMGP_20072023.csv')
head(DatExp)
dim(DatExp)
MediaDatExp <- mean(DatExp$ProgressExplorationsMeters)
MinDatExp <- min(DatExp$ProgressExplorationsMeters)
MaxDatExp <- max(DatExp$ProgressExplorationsMeters)
SdDatExp <- sd(DatExp$ProgressExplorationsMeters)
s <- ggplot(DatExp, aes(Date, ProgressExplorationsMeters))+geom_point()
s
s + geom_smooth()
```

El resultado es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el aviso es:

```
> s + geom_smooth(method='lm')
`geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las variables de **X** y **Y** deben de ser numéricas para que genere esta línea de tendencia. Asimismo, si las variables de **X** es una fecha se debe de convertir a formato Fecha:

```
DatExp$DateYmd <- as.Date(DatExp$DateYmd, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Y te dará como resultado la conversión a formato `Date`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si aparece, por error había obviado la línea tendencia. Gracias